# How do you convert a SnapKit ConstraintItem to an integer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, snapkit

How can I convert a SnapKit ConstraintItem to an integer in Swift? For example, how would I convert the below ConstraintItem to an integer that is usable?

```
view.snp.width
```

Answer (score -4):

Try `view.snp.width.constraint.constant`.